# How to properly pass a pointer to a function in C++ for another function operating directly on that pointer?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am learning to create C++ applications using SDL2 library and I encountered a problem while trying to organise my code.

Here's a simple example ilustrating the situation:

```
void createWindow (SDL_Window *gameWindow)
{
    gameWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(/* arguments here */);
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Window* gameWindow = NULL;
    createWindow(gameWindow);
    // some code here...
}
```

Why doesn't it work? When I try to compile the code, SDL_GetError() screams: "Invalid Renderer".

When I make it that way

```
SDL_Window* createWindow (SDL_Window* gameWindow)
{ 
    gameWindow = SDL_CreateWindow (/* arguments here*/);
    return gameWindow;
}
```

it works. But I don't like it that way.

I may not understand something about pointers or the way SDL2 works on them, but I thought passing one to the function lets me operate directly on the variables intead of copies, so I don't have to return anything. For me it looks like I was operating on the copy of the variable adress, but not the variable itself.

Comment: What about: `SDL_Window* createWindow ()  { return SDL_CreateWindow (/* arguments here*/); }`

Comment: You're changing `createWindow`'s copy of the pointer.

Comment: Even if you don't like it, most people would prefer simply returning the pointer here. Note that the SDL function does just that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arguments in C are *passed by value*, that is, arguments are copied and every modification applied to arguments in a function alters the value of **that copy, not the actually passed argument**.

Resolve the problem by

- **passing a reference to a pointer**:

  ```
  void createWindow (SDL_Window*& gameWindow)
  {
      gameWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(/* arguments here */);
  }
  ```
- **passing a pointer to a pointer**. Watch out: this is C-ish and bad C++ code!

  ```
  void createWindow (SDL_Window** gameWindow)
  {
      *gameWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(/* arguments here */);
  }
  ```
- **returning the pointer**:

  ```
  SDL_Window* createWindow()
  {
      return SDL_CreateWindow(/* arguments here */);
  }
  ```

Comment: I'll advise to use the "returning pointer version" this is clearer. The others versions are confusing.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass your pointer it gets passed by value!
So you are just changing the adress of the local copy in your function

Solution:

```
void createWindow(SDL_Window **gameWindow)
{
     *game_Window = SDL_CreateWindow(/*...*/);
}

int main()
{
      SDL_Window* gameWindow = NULL;
      createWindow(&gameWindow);
}
```

this way you give the adress of your pointer to the function and enable it to change the value of it!

Comment: Do not use pointers to pointers in C++. Use references or return the value.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a pointer, but you are trying to assign the pointer itself.
Try passing by reference, like so:

```
void createWindow (SDL_Window *& gameWindow)
```

Hope this helps. The rest of the code should not be altered for this to work.

Answer (score -1):

It's not about how SDL works, but how c++ handles paramemters.

When you pass any variable as a parameter to a function, the default behavior is to take the value of the variable and copy to the variable inside the function. So.. in your case when you do.

createWindow( gameWindow ); What is going on under the hood is just passing NULL as parameter. If you want to modify the gameWindow pointer, you have to pass it's address.

for example:

```
void createWindow( SDL_Window ** pointer ) { 
    *pointer = SDL_CreateWindow( /** args **/ );
}
```

And call it: `createWindow( &gameWindow );`

You can see a deep explanation about that on that question: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: Do not use pointers to pointers in C++. Use references or return the value.

Comment: Can you point me to something explaining why pointer to pointer is a bad thing?

Comment: [Here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/56935/why-are-pointers-not-recommended-when-coding-with-c) and [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/163393/whats-so-bad-about-pointers-in-c). Pointers to pointers specifically because they are even easier to get wrong and references and the C++ standard library do a much better, safer, and more beautiful job. Also, it's not only about passing variables but expressions in general.

Comment: More generally, you should (almost) _never_ accept a pointer argument if null pointer is not an acceptable value.